# Ansible: How to get variable name from variable

Tags: ansible

I want to use variable name and data in variable at the same time. Like this..

```
- vars: 
    my_var: 
      attr1: Hello world
      attr2: yes
  debug: 
    msg: "This is variable name > my_var. And this is data inside `attr1` > {{ my_var.attr1 }}"
```

How do I get variable name from variable.

Comment: Are you interested to variables local to the task only or do you want to see in upper scopes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html)

```yaml
- vars:
    var_name: my_var 
    my_var: 
      attr1: Hello world
      attr2: yes
  debug: 
    msg: "This is variable name > {{ var_name }}. And this is data inside `attr1` > {{ lookup('vars', var_name).attr1 }}"
```